# Apollo graphql returning entire subdocument collection with each document

Tags: mongodb, apollo, mern, graphql-js

I'm working on a MERN stack with ApolloServer/Client. I wrote a query that should return Building documents (98 documents) with many subfields including an array of their associated Room subdocuments (1-9 subdocuments each, 379 total).

The query works great *except* that each Building document is being returned with an array of all 379 Room subdocuments.

> I think I've narrowed it down to an issue with ApolloServer. I've confirmed the data in my MongoDB is correct and that the Mongoose call in the resolver returns the correct data. When I run the query to the frontend or in Apollo playground, I get the extra documents.

Here are some paraphrased example code

```js
// MongoDB example
// buildings
{ "_id": 1, "address": "123 main st", "rooms":  [{"_id": 12},{"_id": 15}]},
{ "_id": 2, "address": "125 main st", "rooms":  [{"_id": 11}, {"_id": 16}, {"_id": 13}]},
{ "_id": 3, "address": "222 state st", "rooms":  [{"_id": 14}]}

// rooms
{ "_id": 11, "number": "b7"},
{ "_id": 12, "number": "145"},
{ "_id": 13, "number": "12"},
// etc...
```

```js
// Query
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    Buildings: ()=> await Buildings.find({}).populate('rooms') // this returns correctly
  }
}
```

```js
// Typedefs

type Building {
  _id: ID!
  address: String!
  rooms: [Room]
}

type Room {
  _id: ID!
  number: String!
}

query {
  Buildings: [Building]
}

/* Something about this is returning 
{[
  {_id: 1, address: whatever, rooms: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]},
  {_id: 2, address: whatever, rooms: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]},
  {_id: 3, address: whatever, rooms: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]}
]}
instead of
{[
  {_id: 1, address: whatever, rooms: [ 12, 15, ]},
  {_id: 2, address: whatever, rooms: [ 11, 13, 16 ]},
  {_id: 3, address: whatever, rooms: [ 14 ]}
]}
```

I'm working in a sizable code base. I've searched for any duplicated name functions in the typedefs like 'buildings' and 'rooms', but haven't found any. Suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that `await Buildings.find({}).populate('rooms')` returns the *correct* results.

I suspect that there is a type resolver for `Building/rooms` that has an incorrect query tied to it. Your typeDefs are fine, this is going to be in your resolvers code somewhere.

Ideally your `Buildings` query should just return `[Building]` then the resolver for the `rooms` field under `Building` should go figure out what rooms belong to a particular building and return `[Room]`

Comment: You nailed it. I thought I checked everywhere, but I did not. You helped me look even further into my legacy spaghetti and found an import that was otherwise not being used.